# Implementing UserDetails and CredentialsContainer in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to erase the user's credentials after login, so i'm implementing UserDetails and CredentialsContainer in my Account class.

```
@Entity
public class Account implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {
...
```

However, in the docs it says that CredentialsContainer is ***For internal framework use only***.

So I was wondering if this can be a problem in the future.

Comment: If it's for internal use, why are you implementing it. Any good reason? I can understand implementing UserDetails.

Comment: CredentialsContainer has the method `eraseCredentials`, which I use to erase the users password after he logged in, this is the default behavior, you can change this using `erase-credentials="false"`.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but it is not recommended to fool around with plaintext password. Secondly, there are legal limitations which your app can have because you have access to plaintext password. Also, there is a particularly good reason called as Security, that is why the default value of erase-credentials is true. Also, this still doesn't explain why you want to implement that class, you told me its functionality, not what you want to do with it.

Comment: Just to maintain its default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the interface. However, it isn't intended to be implemented if you are writing your own AuthenticationProvider. From the javadoc:

> For internal framework use only. Users who are writing their own
>   AuthenticationProvider implementations should create and
>   return an appropriate Authentication object there, minus
>   any sensitive data, rather than using this interface.

So you can implement it so that Spring Security will call eraseCredentials on your app. However, it is not recommended for you to invoke eraseCredentials on the `CredentialsContainer`.